# Mysql трехкратная выборка из одной таблицы

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица `date`, `time`, `id`, `ip`. Необходимо сделать выборку:

1. Определить все значения `ip` с данным `id`
2. Найти все `id` с такими же `ip`.

   Решение:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip IN ( SELECT ip FROM table WHERE id = значение)
   ```
3. Выбрать совпадения `ip` по дням, так как IP-адреса динамические и поэтому интересуют в рамках одной сессии.

   Указанный в п.2 вариант выдаёт из таблицы совпадения по всем `ip`, а их, как понятно из условия, много лишних...

Comment: используйте distinct, как и написано в одном из ответов к вопросу, на который вам уже давали сегодня ссылку.

Comment: к сожалению, выборка с DISCINCT очень грубая. нужна более детальная. проблема в том, что СУБД выбирает все IP и выкладывает их в результат даже тогда, когда строки с id с запрашиваемым значением нет в этот период времени нет. То есть в этот день пользователь с таким IP не посещал сайт, а оно выдает результат, так как другой пользователь с таким IP посещал.

Comment: так добавьте нужные условия в один или оба `where`. обратите внимание, кстати, что по поводу дат в самом вашем вопросе нет ни слова. я бы всё-таки порекомендовал вам прочитать хотя бы этот раздел справки: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: не могли бы вы показать куда именно добавить условие по дате? куда бы я его не поставил, результат не тот.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table WHERE data IN (SELECT data FROM table WHERE id_number = значение)
AND WHERE id_ip IN (SELECT id_ip FROM table WHERE id_number = значение) такой вариант не работает =( Что можно еще сделать?

Comment: *куда именно добавить условие по дате* — зависит от того, что именно вам нужно. сформулируйте, пожалуйста, ваши требования и дополните текст вопроса. *такой вариант не работает* — «такой» вариант, конечно, работает, но выдаёт не то, что вы ожидаете. подтяните, пожалуйста, теоретические познания по языку sql вообще и аргументу `distinct` в частности: метод «научного тыка» обычно не самый эффективный и продуктивный способ познания.

Comment: Таблица, состоящая из 4 столбцов date, time, id, ip  . Сначала надо найти все записи по определенному ID. Затем из выбранных записей IP и сделать выборку из таблицы. Затем, из полученной выборки отфильтровать только те записи с выбранными ip, которые совпадают по data с ID, значение которого было введено.

Comment: извините, пожалуйста, но вы пишете бессвязно. я не готов тратить время на то, чтобы просить вас объяснить почти каждое написанное вами предложение.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip IN ( SELECT ip FROM table WHERE id = значение)
AND WHERE date IN (SELECT date FROM table WHERE id = значение)  вот что я хочу, но оно почему-то не работает. Причем выборка по отдельности работает, а вместе нет.

Comment: 1. `and where` — ключевое слово `where` здесь лишнее. 2. что именно означает выражение «не работает»?

Comment: alexander barakin, спасибо! =) намучались со мной. Все заработало.  Только теперь мне еще бы хотелось отсортировать еще более детально. Дело в том, что сейчас подставляются все ip, выбранные из строки со id-значением. А как можно сделать, чтобы подставлялись ip, которые получены в определенный день (дата соответствующей строки), а не за весь период?

Comment: Я имею в виду. чтобы подставлялись ip, которые получены от записи за определенный день и в остальные дни чтобы записи с этим ip не выбирало?

Comment: логичнее всего заменить `date in (...)` на `date = значение`

Comment: но ведь мне нужны записи за весь период, но только чтобы IP адрес был выбран не со всего периода, а за дату каждой записи. Например 01.01.2014 IP адрес был 192.168.1.1, а 04.01.2014 10.16.1.10, зачем мне 04.01.2014 искать похожие ID с адресом 192.168.1.1 ?

Comment: В случае, если указать конкретную дату, то произведется выборка за конкретный день по всем IP, выбранным за весь период... может попробовать через создание временной таблицы?

Comment: «по всем IP, выбранным за весь период» — а вам нужны ip только за определённую дату? так добавьте это условие в оператор `select ip ...`

Comment: мне нужно чтобы IP выбирало по совпадению с IP, значение которого находится в строчке ID, но не со всей выборки, а за каждый конкретный день. Чтобы оно автоматически находило день использования и искало совпадения по IP в этот день, а не за весь период.

Comment: обе фразы из вашего последнего комментария можно трактовать двояко — с диаметрально противоположными смыслами. попробуйте упростить описание или, лучше, привести наглядный пример: какие строки вы хотите получить в результирующем запросе, а какие — нет.

Comment: давайте попробую за вас сформулировать, а вы скажете, угадал я или нет. итак. известен id пользователя, который подключался (к примеру) в день1 с адресов адрес1 и адрес2, а в день2 с адресов адрес3 и адрес4. требуется найти id-ы всех пользователей, которые подключались в день1 с адресов адрес1 ИЛИ адрес2. также требуется найти id-ы всех пользователей, которые подключались в день2 с адресов адрес3 ИЛИ адрес4.

Comment: Именно об этом я и спрашиваю, alexander barakin ! ;) Вы правильно поняли! Как это сделать одним запросом ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
select t1.*
 from table t1
 left join table t2
  on t2.id = значение
  and t1.date = t2.date
  and t1.ip = t2.ip
  and t1.id <> t2.id;
```